# What does @internal actually mean and how to use it?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

What does the `@internal` tag mean when used in PHPDocs and how does it work? I have read [the documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html) for this tag and have gotten this definition.

> The @internal tag is used to denote that associated Structural Elements are elements internal to this application or library. It may also be used inside a long description to insert a piece of text that is only applicable for the developers of this software.

I get the gist of it but what I don't understand is how would I actually use it in a project? I've read the example and my understanding is that a function marked as `@internal` means that it's meant to be used as part of the software and not to be used by something external. For example, in a PHP library, if a function is marked as `@internal` it's not part of the public API that the library provides.

My questions:

- Is my understanding of `@internal` correct? If not, what's the correct usage?
- If my understanding *is* correct, why does PhpStorm strike out my `@internal` functions implying they aren't meant to be used? How would I properly use a function marked as `@internal`?

Comment: Here is an example from their docs:  http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.internal.pkg.html   You are understanding it correctly, however I'm not sure why PhpStorm strikes it out unless it is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: It crosses it out just for that reason: to tell you that this method/field/class/etc should not be used outside of the class. I believe that ATM it uses styling for "deprecated" style. Thing is -- it's only basic support -- the ticket is not yet closed -- you are welcome to watch after it to get notified on progress: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-22284

Comment: Thank you both for the information and the link to the PhpStorm issue! I'm glad my understanding was clear and it was simply an issue with PhpStorm's support that was confusing me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is PhpStorm [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31674). It should not strike `@internal` methods used inside of library/package.

So yes, your understand of meaning of `@internal` tag is correct - it is for mark public/protected methods as not a part of public API. You should ignore these warnings for usage inside of library.

Technically there is nothing that will stop you from using such methods even for 3rd party libraries, but you should be aware of consequences - there is no backward compatibility promise for them, so they can be changed, renamed or completely disappear without any warning.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is the comment for programmer about some specific usages.
I mark my recommendations in which cases to use this function or alternative one (e.g. 'use this func in CLI mode only' or 'use this function only if you need row data. Pls consider wrapper in all other cases')

https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html

@internal
The @internal tag is used to denote that associated Structural Elements are elements internal to this application or library. It may also be used inside a long description to insert a **piece of text that is only applicable for the developers of this software.**

Comment: This is the interpretation that I'm familiar with. I would explain it as "documentation that's relevant for future changes of this *class* but not important to callers of this method from outside this class".

Answer (score 1):

Might be trivial for some but it's a good thing to note that declaring a function private if possible is probably better than using `@internal`.

Not saying there are no valid uses for this tag but it's always a good choice to review your design if feel like you need to use it.